# Use JSON Transformer to add element to object root

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to use JSON transformers in Play! so I don't need to serialize from `JSON -> Scala -> JSON` but I'm having trouble using the transformers to add fields to my incoming JSON object.

My javascript app posts an object to my play controller.  The action needs to add 3 fields to the inbound object, and then publish it to RabbitMQ.

Say this is the object posted to my controller

```
{
  price: 300,
  sku: 1234
}
```

I am trying to transform it into

```
{
  createdBy: someone@example.com,
  created: //Date in ISO format,
  id: 4321,
  price: 300,
  sku: 1234
}
```

Here is what I have

```
val id = java.util.UUID.randomUUID
val created = getDateAsIso()
val trnsfm = (__ \ 'user).json.put(user.email) andThen
             (__ \ 'created).json.put(created) andThen
             (__ \ 'id).json.put(id)

val payload = request.body.transform(trnsfm)
```

The result is a JsSuccess with only one element, the last one in the transform value

```
JsSuccess({"id":"9f76bb9a-82b4-43e4-9afe-84ccb4b6dcc0"},)
```

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do in the *coast-to-coast* style, or am I stuck serializing/deserializing?

**Update**

The code @Travis Brown provided is pretty close to working, but I needed to set the values using the JsString classes

```
val trnsfm = __.json.update((__ \ 'user).json.put(JsString(user.email))) andThen
         __.json.update((__ \ 'created).json.put(JsString(created))) andThen
         __.json.update((__ \ 'id).json.put(JsString(id)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`put` effectively ignores its input, so you'll need to use it in conjunction with `update`:

```
val trnsfm = __.json.update((__ \ 'user).json.put(user.email)) andThen
             __.json.update((__ \ 'created).json.put(created)) andThen
             __.json.update((__ \ 'id).json.put(id))
```

If this is the only operation you're performing on the input JSON, transformers may not be the best solution (the `+` and `++` methods on `JsObject` would be a lot more concise, for example).

Comment: I would like to use `+` and `++` but `request.body` is of type `JsValue` not `JsObject`.  I don't know how to convert it.

Comment: You can use `.asOpt[JsObject]` (or `.as[JsObject]`, since YOLO).

Comment: Clarification - I don't know how to create a `JsObject` from a `JsValue`

Comment: A `JsValue` may be a `JsObject` (i.e. `JsObject <: JsValue`). `asOpt` provides a type-safe down-cast.

Answer (score 0):

```
val trnsfm = __.json.update( 
  (
    (__ \ 'user).json.put(JsString("someone@example.com")) and
    (__ \ 'created).json.put(JsNumber(1324132)) and
    (__ \ 'id).json.put(JsNumber(324123))
  )reduce
)
```